# Script collection installation

Tags: python, installation

I need to use the collection of scripts [agpy](https://code.google.com/p/agpy/). How am I supposed to install it? I tried to run `sudo python setup.py` but I got the following error:

```
File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
with open('CHANGES') as file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CHANGES'
```

In the package I downloaded there is no `CHANGES` file/directory. How do you suggest to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this`sudo easy_install agpy`

or `sudo pip install agpy` (better)